# Remove unwanted space at the right of the reference field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and try to put `""` between each `<field>`

```
, (+'"') + isnull(convert(VARCHAR(40), GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo, 120), '') (+ '"') AS ["IdentityNumber"]
```

Data Type

```
referenceInfo nvarchar(40)
```

Result

http://postimg.org/image/rlkxwjthx/

The output data `"10012    "` has a space at the right of the field. How do I remove it?

Comment: RTRIM(your field) or LTRIM(you field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the LTRIM(RTRIM(your field))

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(your field))
```

it will remove the space from right and left both
if you need from one side then just use the  LTRIM(field) for left spacing and RTRIM(field)
for right spacing 
thanks :D

Comment: Yes.I put rtrim function and it's work.., (+'"') + (rtrim(GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo)) + '"' AS ["IdentityNumber"]..thanks much for helping guys

Answer (score 0):

**LTRIM** - removes spaces from left side of string

**RTRIM** - removes any spaces from right side

you can use RTRIM in your case and put your variable inside.

```
RTRIM("foo     ")  // output will be "foo"
```